# Loading JSON stream from Logstash to Elasticsearch

Tags: json, parsing, elasticsearch, unicode, logstash

I'm trying to load JSON stream (lines of json objects file) through logstash to elasticsearch. Some of my json object field contains unicode as you can see below.

```
{"status_link": "https://www.facebook.com/asia/videos/1118055131588324/", "num_loves": "4", "num_sads": "0", "num_wows": "0", "num_angrys": "0", "num_comments": "6", "num_reactions": "46", "num_hahas": "0", "link_name": "", "num_likes": "42", "timestamp": "2016-07-25 02:07:38", "num_shares": "8", "_id": "156915824368931_1118055131588324", "status_message": "\"\u0411\u0440\u0438\u0433\u0430\u0434\" \u0440\u0435\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0442\u0438 \u0448\u043e\u0443\u043d\u044b \u0448\u0438\u043d\u044d \u0434\u0443\u0433\u0430\u0430\u0440 07-\u0440 \u0441\u0430\u0440\u044b\u043d 28-\u043d\u044b \u043f\u04af\u0440\u044d\u0432 \u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0433\u0438\u0439\u043d \u043e\u0440\u043e\u0439 18:00 \u0446\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0430\u0441", "status_type": "video"}
```

When I start logstash, it gives me an error:

```
"status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$StringFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.internal.IdFieldMapper$IdFieldType on field _id"}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

My logstash.conf:

```
input
{
    file
    {
        path => "test.json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        exclude => "*.gz"
        type => "posts"
        codec => "json"
    }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "fb"
  codec => "json"
   }
}
```

I tried to load json object without unicode, it successfully parses and indexes in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have an `_id` field in your document. `_id` is a preserved field. So you need to either remove or rename it.

Comment: Later on I'm loading comments and make it parent-child relation with posts. So isn't the _id field only field that makes the connection between posts and comments?

Comment: If you want to use `_id` as your document id, my suggestion rename it as id and use `document_id => "%{[event][id]}"` in your elasticsearch output.